# Can't get generative.test working with pedestal.io

Tags: clojure, pedestal

Here is my recipe for failure:

> lein new pedestal-app generative-app

I then modify project.clj to be the following:

```
(defproject generative-app "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :repl-options {:init (use 'dev)}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/test.generative "0.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1586"]
                 [domina "1.0.1"]
                 [ch.qos.logback/logback-classic "1.0.7" :exclusions [org.slf4j/slf4j-api]]
                 [io.pedestal/pedestal.app "0.1.10"]
                 [io.pedestal/pedestal.app-tools "0.1.10"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:source-paths ["dev"]}}
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :source-paths ["app/src" "app/templates"]
  :resource-paths ["config"]
  :target-path "out/"
  :aliases {"dumbrepl" ["trampoline" "run" "-m" "clojure.main/main"]})
```

basically, I added `test.generative` and also made it execute `(use 'dev)` at startup.

I then enter the project and type `lein repl`, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/tools/namespace/find__init.class or clojure/tools/namespace/find.clj on classpath: 
....
at io.pedestal.app_tools.server$eval3008$loading__4910__auto____3009.invoke(server.clj:12)
....
at dev$eval1071$loading__4910__auto____1072.invoke(dev.clj:1)
```

Clearly, when `(use 'dev)` is run, something goes haywire. I don't really know what.

If anyone would like to take a swing at it, I put the steps above into a project at git@github.com:samedhi/generative-app.git ,
so you can simply

```
> git clone git@github.com:samedhi/generative-app.git
> cd generative-app
> lein repl
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from clojure.tools.namespace.

Run `lein deps :tree` to show the dependency tree - in this case, the relevant bits are:

```
[io.pedestal/pedestal.app-tools "0.1.11-20130719.140954-2"]
   [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.1"]
```

and

```
[org.clojure/test.generative "0.4.0"]
  [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.1.1"]
```

You can see the conflict - `test.generative 0.4.0` depends on an earlier version of `tools.namespace`.

Add an exclusion to the relevant line of your `project.clj`:

```
[org.clojure/test.generative "0.4.0" :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.namespace]]
```

This will make the project compile, and you can run `(use dev)` and `(start)` fine.  However, there's a risk that after excluding `tools.namespace 0.1.1`, test.generative will no longer work (if it relies on functions that were in `tools.namespace 0.1.1` and subsequently deprecated). Hopefully everything will be fine, but if not, you may need to wait for `test.generative` to catch up with the later version of `tools.namespace`.